# Win32/C++: How do I assign a tooltip for a specific treeview item?

Tags: c++, winapi

**Note: This is pure WinAPI/C++, no MFC/WTL/ATL please**

So I have a treeview called `CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree`. It has an item in it called `CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root` that says "**CarbonCoffee Toolbox**" (in bold, since I used custom draw). It also has its `HTREEITEM` which is called `CC_HTI_Start_TaskTree_root`. As you may have noticed from the names, the item is the **root** of the tree-view.

What I'm trying to do here is setting a specific tooltip for the root and different tooltips for its children, since different items in the treeview are responsible for different things. When I use the `TreeView_SetToolTips` function on the `HWND`, the tooltip appears when my cursor is on the treeview, not on the actual item. I also have other items in the tree but to keep it simple I'll exclude them. This is what I've tried so far:

```cpp
    HWND CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree = CreateWindowEx(0, WC_TREEVIEW, _T("Task Tree"), WS_CHILD | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL | TVS_HASBUTTONS | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_INFOTIP | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_SHOWSELALWAYS, 18, 103, 447, 506, CC_CTRL_W_Start, (HMENU)ID_CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree, CC_HI_Main, 0);
    TreeView_SetBkColor(CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree, RGB(76, 76, 76));
    TreeView_SetTextColor(CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree, RGB(255, 255, 255));
    TreeView_SetLineColor(CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree, RGB(245, 245, 245));
    SendMessage(CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)CC_F_Main, 0);

    CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root.hItem = CC_HTI_Start_TaskTree_root;
    CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root.mask = TVIF_TEXT | TVIF_IMAGE | TVIF_SELECTEDIMAGE | TVIF_PARAM;
    CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root.pszText = (LPTSTR)_T("CarbonCoffee Toolbox");
    CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root.cchTextMax = sizeof(CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root.pszText);
    CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root.lParam = (LPARAM)0;
    CC_TVINSERTSTRUCT_Main.item = CC_TVI_Start_TaskTree_root;
    CC_TVINSERTSTRUCT_Main.hInsertAfter = CC_HTI_Start_TaskTree_root;
    CC_HTI_Start_TaskTree_root = (HTREEITEM)SendMessage(CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree, TVM_INSERTITEM, 0, (LPARAM)(LPTVINSERTSTRUCT)&CC_TVINSERTSTRUCT_Main);
    HWND CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL, TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_BALLOON | TTS_CLOSE | WS_POPUP, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CC_CTRL_W_Start, NULL, CC_HI_Main, NULL);
    TOOLINFO CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root = {0};
    CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root.cbSize = sizeof(CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root);
    CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root.hwnd = CC_CTRL_W_Start;
    CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
    CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root.uId = (UINT_PTR)CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree;
    CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root.lParam = (LPARAM)1;
    CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root.lpszText = (LPWSTR)_T("This is the \"root\" of the tree.\nClick the + button to the left\nto view the dozens of tools\nthat CarbonCoffee offers!");
    SendMessage(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, TTM_SETTITLEW, (WPARAM)TTI_INFO, (LPARAM)_T("CarbonCoffee Toolbox"));
    SendMessage(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, TTM_SETDELAYTIME, (WPARAM)TTDT_INITIAL, (LPARAM)3000);
    SendMessage(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, TTM_SETDELAYTIME, (WPARAM)TTDT_RESHOW, (LPARAM)3000);
    SetWindowTheme(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, _T("DarkMode_Explorer"), NULL);
    //SetWindowLongPtr(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)CC_WNDP_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root);
    SendMessage(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)CC_F_Main, (LPARAM)TRUE);
    //SendMessage(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, TTM_TRACKACTIVATE, (WPARAM)FALSE, (LPARAM)&CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root);
    //CC_MouseInfo_TrackingOrNot = FALSE;
    SendMessage(CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&CC_TOOLINFO_Start_TaskTree_root);
    TreeView_SetToolTips(CC_CTRL_Start_TaskTree, CC_TIP_Start_TaskTree_root);
```

But whatever I try, I get the same result. I've been thinking about manually getting some kind of information about the tree item like size and position on the screen in pixels, and then making some kind of transparent, always-on-top `HWND` with it. But I know it'll break as soon as I scroll, plus I don't really know how to do that. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Respond to `TVN_GETINFOTIP` with the tooltip text.

Comment: @RaymondChen How exactly would I go about doing that? I've tried if statements, but both of them show up at once no matter where I select.

Comment: @HackerDaGreat57 did you [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvn-getinfotip)? Enable the `TVS_INFOTIP` style on the TreeView, and then handle the `TVN_GETINFOTIP` message is the *parent window*'s WndProc. The parent window can then fill in the `NMTVGETINFOTIP::pszText` field as needed, based on the provided `NMTVGETINFOTIP::hItem` and `NMTVGETINFOTIP::lParam` fields. No need to use your own tooltips manually

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to Win32 :( I need sample code. Both tooltips still show themselves at the same time. Yes, I have enabled `TVS_INFOTIP` and it was there ever since I tried adding tooltips.

By the way, this isn't homework, it's a hobby project so please don't feel guilty giving me source code ;)

Comment: [How to Use Tree-View Infotip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-tree-view-infotips)

Comment: That works **wonderfully!** Thank you so much .